# Best way to map Pandas column using dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary that who's keys are names and values are another dictionary which maps numbers to their normalized values (essentially just numbers to numbers). For example:

```
dict1 = {'name1':{0.02:0.04, 0.034:0.06, 0.051:0.08...0.59:0.71, 0.611:0.723}}
```

I have a dataframe `df` of ~5 million rows. One column is named `Value`. Another is `Name`. Overall, I want to add an extra column `Mapped` that uses `Value` and maps it using `dict1`. I need to use the `Name` column to look up in the outer dictionary in `dict1` and then the `Value` column to look up in the inner dictionary. However, `Value` may not be a key in `dict1` -- if it isn't, I want to take the closet key.

This is what I have that I know works, but it has been running for a pretty long time:

```
df['Map'] = df.apply(lambda row: dict1[row['Name']][min(dict1[row['Name']].keys(), key = lambda k: abs(row['Value'] - k))], axis = 1)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this so it does not take forever?

Example `df`:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   Name    Value
0  'name1'  0.02
1  'name1'  0.03
2  'name1'  0.6
```

Here's the output I would want:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   Name    Value    Map
0  'name1'  0.02    0.04
1  'name1'  0.03    0.06
2  'name1'  0.6     0.71
```

Comment: can you provide an example of your data and expected output?

Comment: My hunch is that this performs poorly because the sub-dicts in `dict1` are fairly large and `min` must iterate over the entire list of keys each time. This is an expensive set of operations. If you expect most of the values in your second dict to be present, you can speed this up significantly by doing a first pass and setting `None` is your new column where the desired key is not present, then doing a second pass where you only run your `min` function for rows with `None`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Added.

Comment: "A dictionary which maps numbers to their normalized values" what is the logic for value normalization? It might be easier/faster to perform the normalization inside pandas, instead of saving the normalization results to a dictionary.

Comment: @jfaccioni How would I do that? I have a specific type of normalization.

Comment: In other words, you want to map `('name1', 0.02)` to `0.04`, but why `('name2', 0.03)` is mapped to `0.06`. There is no `'name2'` in your `dict1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @formicaman I can't guess how you would do that without looking at your normalization logic, but it *has* to have some sort of logic, otherwise it's not normalization. For example, If you are performing group-wise normalization, using a groupby object in pandas would be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `merge_asof`:

```
# prepare data for merge
s = (pd.DataFrame(dict1).stack()
       .reset_index(name='Map')
       .sort_values(['level_0','Map'])
    )

# output
(pd.merge_asof(df, s, 
               left_on='Value', right_on='level_0',
               left_by='Name', right_by='level_1',
               direction='nearest')
   .drop(['level_0', 'level_1'], axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
    Name  Value   Map
0  name1   0.02  0.04
1  name1   0.03  0.06
2  name1   0.60  0.71
```

Comment: This looked like it work and was done within 10 seconds. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Finding the nearest key is naturally slow since it needs to scan through the whole dict. If the mapping doesn't change, you could precompute useful things about it, such as a sorted order of the keys, which you can then use to do a fast binary search using the built-in `bisect` module, and you can additionally cache the results using `lru_cache`. Hope this helps...

```
import bisect
from functools import lru_cache


class ValueMapping:
    def __init__(self, data: dict):
        self.data = data
        self.keys = list(sorted(data))
        self.min_key = self.keys[0]
        self.max_key = self.keys[-1]
        self.find = lru_cache(maxsize=1024)(self._find)  # cache results for find

    def _find(self, key):
        if key in self.data:  # Exact match
            return (key, self.data[key])
        if key < self.min_key:  # Lower than the known minimum
            return (self.min_key, self.data[self.min_key])
        if key > self.max_key:  # Higher than the known maximum
            return (self.max_key, self.data[self.max_key])

            # Otherwise, bisect
        nearest_idx = bisect.bisect(self.keys, key)
        nearest_key = self.keys[nearest_idx]
        return (nearest_key, self.data[nearest_key])


mapping = ValueMapping({k * 0.1: (k + 1) ** 0.5 for k in range(0, 50)})

for x in range(10):
    x = (x - 1) / 10 - 0.15
    key, val = mapping.find(x)
    print("%f, %f, %f" % (x, key, val))
```

This prints out approximately

```
-0.250000, 0.000000, 1.000000
-0.150000, 0.000000, 1.000000
-0.050000, 0.000000, 1.000000
0.050000, 0.100000, 1.414214
0.150000, 0.200000, 1.732051
0.250000, 0.300000, 2.000000
0.350000, 0.400000, 2.236068
0.450000, 0.500000, 2.449490
0.550000, 0.600000, 2.645751
0.650000, 0.700000, 2.828427
```

Comment: This solution requires the keys in the sub-dicts to be sorted before hand.

Comment: There is no such thing as key order in dicts (except as an implementation detail). `self.keys = list(sorted(data))` sorts the keys for bisection.

Comment: That was once true, but is no longer as of Python 3.7 (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html). But that's entirely besides the point.  The point is that this implementation requires the keys to be sorted which I think goes  O(nlogn). `min` is only O(n). Unless I am missing something.

Comment: (As I said "(except as an implementation detail)". Yes, dicts in CPython 3.7 retain insertion order, but that's not in the language spec.) The idea here, anyway, is that the mappings are presumed to not change, so sorting keys and finding min/max can be done once, after which finding mapped values outside the mapping range is O(1) and finding the nearest value is O(log n) (binary search over the keys).

Comment: Sure, the dict can be modified ahead of time. And as indicated in the announcement linked above, key order preservation is now _guaranteed_. It is part of the language spec as of 3.7 per edict of the BDFL. So it is no longer an implementation detail.

Comment: Fair, I hadn't known it became part of the actual language spec too. Still, it's insertion order, not sort order :)

Comment: And we've come full circle: "This solution requires the keys in the sub-dicts to be sorted before hand." Which, to your point, is being done on `__init__`.